# display error message on wordpress login

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display error message on wp-login form when captcha code is incorrect.. i m using 'login_redirect' and 'login_errors' filters..here is my code..

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'captcha_login_check', 10, 3);
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'captcha_login_post' );
function captcha_login_check($username, $password)
{
if (isset($_POST["security_check"])) 
{
    $code = str_decrypt($_POST["security_check"]);
    if (!( empty($code)) && !($code == $_POST['security_code'] ) && ($password == false))
    {
        function captcha_login_post($error)
        {
            return $error."<p><span style='color:red'>Error, the Security Code does not match. Please Try Again.</span><br></p>";
        }

    }
    else if(!( empty($code)) && !($code == $_POST['security_code'] ) && ($password == true))
    {
        $url = get_site_url().'/wp-login.php'; 
        header('Location:'.$url);
        echo  "<p><span style='color:red'>Error, the Security Code does not match. Please Try Again.</span><br></p>";

    }
    else
    {
        $url = get_site_url().'/wp-admin'; 
        header('Location:'.$url);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84402/how-to-display-error-messages-using-wp-error-class

Comment: its not working.. i already tried this one.. error comes 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string'

Comment: hope this will be helpful http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-error-messages-in-custom-login-form

Comment: i used this one also.. not works in my case..

Comment: i want to display error on login form..my 'else' case is working,it redirects to wp-admin..but 'if' part not display error message when captcha code mismatches